# Peculiarity of chemo senses

Tags: physiology, neurophysiology, human-physiology, senses

We can easily recall our visual stimulus and auditory stimulus but why can't we recall chemical stimulus like smell and pain?

We can recall a song or picture but we can't exactly recall smell and pain. Why is that so?

Comment: This appears, at least to me, a very subjective question that would have to be discussed philosophically rather than with empirical evidence. An interesting topic nonetheless!

Comment: Olfactory memories are among the most powerful known. They are **so** strong that copious salivation occurs when people are directed to think of biting into a lemon or a sourball. What is the basis for your question?

Comment: I mean can you imagine a smell of jasmine as visualizing it?